# Display Javadoc with Autocomplete Parameter Information in Intellij

Tags: autocomplete, intellij-idea, javadoc

In Eclipse, when you're about to enter parameters for a method, the auto-complete will display all possible combinations as well as the Javadoc associated with each of them. This can also be triggered manually.

I'm trying to get Intellij to display the same information but I can only get it to display the shortened parameter information via Control-P. Is there a way to display the corresponding Javadocs as well?

For the example below, in Eclipse, you can get the Javadoc for each of the different Date constructors to show up before entering anything. But in Intellij, I can only get the JavaDocs to display after entering ALL of the parameters then performing a Control-Q on the method. I can't get the Javadocs to display while typing.

In this case, it's trivial but sometimes the parameter names are not labeled so Javadocs are nice to help pick which overloaded method you want.

Eclipse:

[image: Eclipse]

Intellij:

[image: Intellij]

Comment: Have you tried pressing Ctrl+P, then using the arrow keys to choose one of the argument signatures and then pressing Ctrl+Q. Sorry, don't have IntelliJ to hand to check this works.

Comment: For me, when I type "Date d = new Date(", it automatically brings up the various constructors & their parameters, after a delay of about a second.  As @theon mentions, I can also put the cursor inside the parens in "Date()" and press ctrl-P and it shows them.  I'm using IntelliJ 11.1.3, but it's done this for as long as I can remember.

Comment: As @theon says, ctrl-P brings up the arguments, but it doesn't let you select one with the arrow keys so you can't do the ^Q to show the Javadocs.  I guess I've always entered the params first, then done ^Q, but I can see how this is annoying if you're used to it happening automatically.  Instead, I'll give you one of my (unrelated) favorite IntelliJ features - ctrl-W - keep pressing it and it selects text, increasing the scope each time.

Comment: Ah yeah. The thing I said doesn't work - just tried. Maybe open a  ticket suggesting it to jetbrains, because it would be be useful.

Comment: Am I missing something here?  I can't get it to show me even the parameter names and there appears to be no way of switching between overloaded methods/constructors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a known limitation, please [vote for this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-18630) in YouTrack (it's 4 years old!).

Comment: So it looks like nothing has changed since?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for this new feature to appear in IntelliJ 2018.2, Go to Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion and open Show the documentation info popup in... options, I just solved this problem with the new version.